# SAP DI Server - How to issue first request?

Tags: soap, sapb1

I have set up a Windows server using SAP Business One, and am trying to fire up the DI Server.

I would like to make a HTTP request with a SOAP body, but I don't know what URL to put in postman.

I also can't figure out how to run the example files in the installation folder for DI Server.

Does anyone know how to get started with DI Server?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are also using B1WS, starting the DI-Server service doesn't give you a listening HTTP server. You need to write your own listener, for instance as a simple .ashx page hosted under IIS, which accepts a request and passes it to the *Interact* method of the *SBODI_Server.Node* object.

See: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/07/28/connecting-an-add-on-to-sap-business-one/

Comment: Hi Daz, does B1WS validates everything or it does the db entry directly. Also I want to integrate JAVA with di server. How to write listener for it.

Comment: @anup ganatra DI Server does the same validation that DI-API does. Writing a listener in Java is beyond the scope of this question.