# SAP B1 DI Server - Initial Request Problems

Tags: java, sapb1

I am trying to integrate with SAP DI Server. I am using B1WS but the fact that it does not allow BatchInteract is a massive drawback.

I have been looking to implement the BatchInteract myself but I am having issues getting started.

I understand that BatchInteract takes multiple SOAP envelopes in the format

```
<Envelopes>

    <Envelope>

      .

      .

      .

    </Envelope>
    ....
</Envelopes>
```

With how the WSDL files are generated, I'm not sure how I would implement this? I don't know exactly where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this is a question about how to set up a listening server on 'B' then see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46543454/1499294

Comment: @Daz I understand that we need to pass the request to a listener (such as a server, or an .ashx hosted under IIS to forward the request). The problem I'm mainly having is to implement BatchInteract for the B1WS.